# RavenDb Strange Behaviour with objects with equality members

Tags: ravendb

I got to the bottom of a strange bug (in my code ) when I was trying to store a list of objects to ravendb. The problem was that the object to be stored has equality members generated by resharper. The object in question is as follows (note that I have commented out the equality members to solve the issue) -

```
//[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
//[KnownType(typeof(IApplicationEntity))]
public class ApplicationEntity: IApplicationEntity
{

    public ApplicationEntity()
    {

    }
    public ApplicationEntity(string processName)
    {
        ProcessName = processName;
        Id = "Processes/" + ProcessName;
    }

    public ApplicationEntity(string key, string processName)
    {
        ProcessName = processName;
        Key = key;
        Id = string.Format("Processes/{0}_{1}", Key, ProcessName);

    }


    //[DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    //[DataMember]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    //[DataMember]
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    //[DataMember]
    public string ProcessDescription { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// used to generate sequential unique activity ID generation only.
    /// </summary>
    //[DataMember]
    public string ActivityCount { get; set; }

    //public bool Equals(ApplicationEntity other)
    //{
    //    if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
    //    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
    //    return Equals(other.ProcessName, ProcessName);
    //}

    //public override bool Equals(object obj)
    //{
    //    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    //    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    //    if (obj.GetType() != typeof (ApplicationEntity)) return false;
    //    return Equals((ApplicationEntity) obj);
    //}

    //public override int GetHashCode()
    //{
    //    return (ProcessName != null ? ProcessName.GetHashCode() : 0);
    //}
}
```

Now if I stored the object with equality members implement then the following code produces strange results -

```
int count = 0;
        using (var session = _store.OpenSession(_databaseName))
        {


            foreach (var applicationEntity in _listOfApplications)
            {
                var entity = new ApplicationEntity(count.ToString(), applicationEntity.ProcessName);


                //ravenRepositoryCachable.Add(entity);
                session.Store(entity);


                count++;


            }

            session.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The strange behaviour is that I would expect the Key field to be incrementing to 400 as the list has 400 members , but instead the Key for the first 10 object stored is correct i.e 0 to 9. but the 11th one started from 0 again and so on.

but if I comment the equality members off(as in the code snippet above) then this problem disappears.

Also If i add the objects one at a time as opposed to batch the problem disappears -

```
int count = 0;
        foreach (var applicationEntity in _listOfApplications)
        {
            using (var session = _store.OpenSession(_databaseName))
            {
                var entity = new ApplicationEntity(count.ToString(), applicationEntity.ProcessName);


                //ravenRepositoryCachable.Add(entity);
                session.Store(entity);
                session.SaveChanges();

                count++;

            }
        }
```

I know I have resolved the issue but I do not understand what happened here and why only the key field was effected? This is a undefined behaviour and I am worried as bit as code is supposed to be deployed in production!! It is clear that the equality members are not to be defined. I need to get to the bottom of it , is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think there is such a bug in RavenDB. Instead, I guess there is another issue with your code, because this test (that is based on your example above) works for me:

```
public class EqualityMembersInSessionCache
{
    public class ApplicationEntity
    {
        public ApplicationEntity(string key, string processName)
        {
            ProcessName = processName;
            Key = key;
            Id = string.Format("Processes/{0}_{1}", Key, ProcessName);
        }


        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string ProcessName { get; set; }


        public bool Equals(ApplicationEntity other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
            return Equals(other.ProcessName, ProcessName);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != typeof(ApplicationEntity)) return false;
            return Equals((ApplicationEntity)obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (ProcessName != null ? ProcessName.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Has_correct_behaviour()
    {
        var randomNames = new List<string>();
        for (int c = 1; c < 100; c++)
        {
            randomNames.Add(string.Format("test{0}", c));
        }

        using (var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true })
        {
            int count = 0;
            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                foreach (var name in randomNames)
                {
                    session.Store(new ApplicationEntity(count.ToString(), name));
                    count++;
                }
                session.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                var results = session.Query<ApplicationEntity>()
                    .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
                    .ToList();

                Assert.NotEmpty(results);
                Assert.Equal(99, results.Count);
                for (int c = 0; c < 99; c++)
                {
                    Assert.Equal(c, int.Parse(results[c].Key));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want us to investigate further on this, please provide a failing test.

Comment: Some differences between your and my code - I am not using the embedded version. I have raven installed as a service.

Comment: If I do it your way there is no problem , this problem is hard to reproduce. It doesn't seem to any problem in my code as if I comment out the equality members the problem goes away. As is evident from my code there are no abstractions and I am using documents stores directly.

Comment: It's no difference if you're using EmbeddableDocumentStore or a installed Service. It is a xUnit-Test, that's one way to reproduce things. If I cannot reproduce this behaviour, I'm not able to tell you if it is a bug (or not) and what you can do about it.